# Django - Redirecting after a POST (but after being logged out)

Tags: python, django, post, redirect

So I'm trying to consider the case where a logged in user has say, 2 tabs open, and logs out of my site in one tab but in the other tab since they're still 'logged in', and they try to click a button which submits POST data, my function in my view should detect that the user is not authenticated and it should redirect them to the login page. However, I can't seem to get this to work at all. I've done numerous testing and I know my condition is getting validated correctly, but the redirect just doesn't happen. Below is the code for the form and the code in my view.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
# an input button
</form>


if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'))

#otherwise I check if it was request.POST etc and handle a normal request
```

I've tried to hard code the url, using the login url specified in my settings file, etc but none of it seems to do anything. I'm thinking it's all because of the empty action="" part but I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: You are  probably losing context becasuse of `HttpResponseRedirect` Use `redirect_to` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like a perfect task for the `login_required` decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: +1 The snippet testing `user.request.is_authenticated()` looks correct and should work, but using the `login_required` decorator would be simpler.

Comment: I've tried @login_required (and retried it again now just to make sure) and specifying the LOGIN_URL in my settings and also put in the url for django.contrib.auth.views.login in my urls.py but it still just doesn't do anything unfortunately. There's still no redirect and it sort of just refreshes the page (and now being logged out)

Comment: Why don't you try posting your entire view/urls/template etc? So we can see the whole picture.